# User Not Found in Db2-mx

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I'm currently enrolled in Relational Database Basics, IBM Course. On the lab assignment, one of the steps is to `Go to UI` in the services page. However, after following the correct steps and clicking on `Go to UI`, the following message appears:

> HWCUSR0012E: User rsc83832 is not found, please ensure that the userId exists.

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming but support question.

Comment: Is'nt the message clear?  You might have the wrong userid, check and double check the spelling.

Comment: @mao I'm already logged in. So here is what i did: Log in > Resource list > Services and Software > Db2-mx. It takes me to a new tab.. it keeps loading then the message appears.